# Dynamic sprite management

Tags: vulkan

I'm learning Vulkan.

So far, in the sample programs that I've done, I've uploaded enough vertices to the GPU for drawing one or two quads. I also uploaded an image to display on the quad. It has all been very static.

I'm now interested in doing some dynamic tests -- specially, creating and modifying sprites on the fly. I'm not sure how to go about it, so I'm hoping to get some pointers about possible techniques. I'm trying to create a toy 2d engine, for learning purposes.

Basically, I'm not sure what's the best way to maintain the vertex data up-to-date on the GPU. Below is the definition for one quad:

```
struct Vertex2d {
    glm::vec3 mPos;
    glm::vec2 mCoord;
};

// Vertices for one quad.
const std::vector<fmk::Vertex2d> quadVertices = {
    {{-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}},   // Vert 0: Top left
    {{0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f},  {1.0f, 0.0f}},   // Vert 1: Top Right
    {{0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f},   {1.0f, 1.0f}},   // Vert 2: Bottom Right
    {{-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f},  {0.0f, 1.0f}},   // Vert 3: Bottom Left
};

const std::vector<uint16_t> quadIndexes = {
    0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0,
};
```

The vertex data represents the quad's position, rotation, scale, texture coordinates. Any of those properties could, potentially, change every frame. Also, new sprites can, potentially, be created or destroyed every frame.

Any pointers on data structures, techniques, functions, or any other info to managing sprites using Vulkan is appreciated.

EDIT:

I should add that I'm trying to avoid brute-force uploading all the vertices every frame. I'm currently trying to implement a brute-force approach, so that I can compare it with a good solution, once I've learned of one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You want to change positions of vertices stored in a buffer, You have two options:

- You upload them from the CPU
- You calculate them on the GPU

There are no other ways for the data to appear on the GPU. You either transfer it or generate.

The first solution is the one You call a brute-force, but in many situations You cannot avoid it. One way or another You have to transfer data to the GPU so it can use it for rendering purposes. Besides, transfer rates are quite high in today's GPUs. It is possible to transfer several dozen of gigabytes per second.

The second option is more procedural and doesn't require data transfer between CPU and GPU. To do that You either create a formula to calculate positions in a vertex shader on the fly, based on a time or any other parameter (without changing the original values). The second option, similar to transform feedback, is to calculate positions in a compute shader, store them in a buffer and then use that buffer for drawing purposes. [Here](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Vulkan-Cookbook/blob/master/Samples/Source%20Files/12%20Advanced%20Rendering%20Techniques/03-Drawing_particles_using_compute_and_graphics_pipelines/main.cpp) is an example from a Vulkan Cookbook which does exactly that - draws particles (sprites) whose positions are calculated in a compute shader.

And don't forget that You don't need to transfer all the data with each vertex. To render a quad You just need a single position (center) and potentially a horizontal and vertical scale (size of the quad in each dimension). Offsets, rotations, translations and other operations don't need to be passes with each vertex, but only for the whole quad. So this also limits the size of the data You may need to transfer.

Comment: I'm using uint16_t type for the indexes, which has max value of 65,535. Since each quad has 4 vertices, the hard limit for the amount of quads that can be drawn in one drawIndexed call is: 65,535 % 4 = 16,383. Each quad is 80 bytes. If I draw the max possible quads, the transfer rate is: 16,383 * 80 / 1024 / 1024 = 1.25MB per frame. At 60fps, that would be 75MB per second of vertex data. I don't have experience with this, but that sounds like too high of data transfer.

Comment: Data transfer is one of the possibilities. I described two, the second being GPU calculations. But apart from that - to draw a quad You need only one vertex, the rest can be generated on the fly in geometry shader.

Comment: ... continue. If I set a soft limit of 10% max hard limit, then that would be 16,383 / 10 = 1,638 quads. 

1,638 * 80 / 1024 / 1024 = 0.125MB per frame. At 60fps, that would be 7.5MB of vertex data per second.

As my toy engine is 2d, the sprites represent the main (only?) display geometry. Characters, bg tiles, etc would all be sprites.

As I'm coding up the tests for the brute force approach, I find that I'm sort of liking it. It allows me to do all calculations on the host side, and upload baked  data.

Comment: It's going to take me a week or 2 to be able to test the limits of the brute force approach (I have limited time for hobby programming). Also, I don't have experience with game/graphics programming, so I don't know if these types of transfer rates are ok or they're ludicrous.

I can only test on my PC, which has a GTX 770. Per gpuinfo.org, it seems that the GTX 6XX series is the oldest GTX to support Vulkan. 

In general, is 10MB per second transfer rate OK for GPUs of GTX 650 calibre? If so, I might just stick with brute force.

Comment: I don't know if it is too much or not (just test it). That's why I provided You an example showing how to calculate positions in a compute shader to avoid transfering data between CPU and GPU.

Comment: The sprites I'm talking about are not for particle systems, so calculating position/rotation/scale info in the GPU doesn't work for this. That info would come from logic calculations done on the host. Appreciate the answer, anyway.

Comment: Sprites are just camera-facing quads with a texture applied. So drawing them is no different than drawing particles. And You can also calculate scale/positions/rotations in a compute shader. It may just be a bit harder than doing so on the CPU. But if You want to perform those calculations on the CPU then, guess what: You need to transfer it to the GPU that way or another. You cannot escape that.

Comment: I've just tested data transfer rates. I copy 36 MB of data from one buffer to another. I do it each frame (not each second, each frame) and still got over 100 FPS on Intel hardware. So this gives over 3 GB of data transfer per second. But looking at some benchmarking sites, Intel's GPUs have even bigger bandwidth - from 20 to 70 GB/s. So I doubt it should be a problem in Your case.

Comment: Wow, that's really nice throughput. In your tests, did you approach this in a naive way: single threaded, no special transfer queue; or did you get fancy with it? I'll still conduct my own tests, for completeness of understanding, but your results are very encouraging. They give me an idea of the type of results that I should expect. If my tests don't meet that, then I know that I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @Dess Yes, it was a quick and simple implementation. I've just added a copy operation from one buffer to the other buffer, which was used as a vertex buffer (a source of vertex data). It was performed in the same command buffer in which drawing was performed. And it was submitted to the same queue (in fact Intel's hardware has only one queue). Everything on a single thread.

Comment: Noice! Thank you